# Environment/system variables in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, environment-variables, system-variable

How can I use environment/system variables in tomcat server.xml, context.xml, etc configuration files?

I tried to use `${ENV_VAR_NAME}` (both for environment and system variable), `${env.ENV_VAR_NAME}` (for environment variables). And nothing seems to work.

Comment: @DagR, unfortunately no

Answer (score 20):

Environment variables can be referenced in the server.xml etc by setting the system property `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE` to the value `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester$EnvironmentPropertySource`.

That system property has been available since 7.0, but `EnvironmentPropertySource` was not mentioned in the doc until 8.5.

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/systemprops.html

Update (April 2020):

The latest tomcat releases (9.0.34, 8.5.54) now support property replacement in most configuration files:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.34_(markt)

Comment: Watch out, because in the near future the `$` in the class name will change to a `.` See https://github.com/apache/tomcat/commit/ffba0c6c97f03e0a32c8a40a1589f93419458ef1

Comment: Just `echo 'org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester$EnvironmentPropertySource' >> conf/catalina.properties` if you find it hard to play with dollar sign in shell script.

Comment: so basically adding `'org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester$EnvironmentPropertySource'` this line to `/tomcat/conf/catalina.properties`? When tomcat is starting, it will resolve tokens in `server.xml` with environment variables? @youfu

Comment: @JonathanHagen Yes.

Comment: Just to note `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.Digester$EnvironmentPropertySource` is now deprecated, at least with Tomcat 9.0.55.  The alternative is `org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource` in catalina.properties: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/tomcat/util/digester/EnvironmentPropertySource.html

Comment: Confirmed this works with Tomcat 8.5.90 + just add "CATALINA_OPTS=-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.digester.PROPERTY_SOURCE=org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.EnvironmentPropertySource" to your setenv.bat and you can then do things like truststoreFile="${JRE_HOME}\\lib\\security\\cacerts" and keystoreFile="${USERPROFILE}\\.keystore"

Answer (score 19):

How it's realized in my box.

Bash-script for startup:

```
#!/bin/sh

SMEMORY=1G
XMEMORY=1G

if [ $ENV == DEV ]; then
  port_shutdown="8005"
  port_http="8080"
  port_https="8443"
elif
  [ $ENV == SIT ]; then
  port_shutdown="8006"
  port_http="8081"
  port_https="8444"
elif
  [ $ENV == UAT ]; then
  port_shutdown="8007"
  port_http="8082"
  port_https="8445"
else
  echo "Unknown ENV"
  exit 1
fi

export CATALINA_OPTS=" ${SYSTEM_PROPS} -d64 -server -Xms$SMEMORY -Xmx$XMEMORY \
 -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64M \
 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M \
 -Dport.http=${port_http} -Dport.https=${port_https} -Dport.shutdown=${port_shutdown}"

exec $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

In `server.xml`:

```
<Connector
  port="${port.http}"
  protocol="HTTP/1.1"
  connectionTimeout="20000"
  redirectPort="${port.https}"
/>
```

Take a look at process:

```
$ ps ux | grep tomcat
... -Xms1G -Xmx1G ... -Denv=KIEV_DEV... -Dport.http=8084 -Dport.https=8446 -Dport.shutdown=8008...
```

Check ports:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep java
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
tcp        0      0 :::8084                     :::*                        LISTEN      23343/java
tcp        0      0 :::8446                     :::*                        LISTEN      23343/java
```

Comment: Can you please reference the official documentation for this? thanks!

Comment: So in a nutshell, you're modifying the tomcat startup environment with custom environment variables that then become accessible from the environment with which the tomcat xml's are parsed (the application memory vs the base linux env).  So in other words, Tomcat cannot access normal BASH env variables but you can inject them into the Tomcat environment in a way that makes them accessible to reference inside of the tomcat xmls, correct?