# Wildfly config file runtime parameter

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

Can we specify environment variable in Wildfly standalone.xml and module.xml file for some runtime configuration?
we can do this in tomcat like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926181/evironment-system-variables-in-server-xml), i tried slimier by using JAVA_OPTS in wildly but its not working.

Comment: why do it via standalone.xml and not in standalone.bat?

Comment: i am using docker and module.xml file need to have some tag which need to set from environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set all the environment variables in standalone.conf.bat(Windows) and standalone.conf(linux) present under WILDFLY_HOME/bin directory.

You can also call them in standalone.xml file using `${env.variable_name}`.
for example:
I have an environment variable DB_CONNECTION_URL and I want to use it in Wildfly. So, I will specify `${env.DB_CONNECTION_URL}` for database connection URL in my wildfly configuration file.