# Tomcat is not replacing system properties in server.xml

Tags: tomcat, catalina

I am having an issue with Tomcat not replacing the system properties set in catalina.properties when it parses server.xml.

In catalina.properties, I set the following properties;

```
server.cipher.suites.List=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV


server.tlsProtocols=TLSv1.2
```

I reference these properties in server.xml like this:

```
    <Connector port="8443"
               protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               maxThreads="150"
               secure="true"
               scheme="https"
               SSLEnabled="true">
      <SSLHostConfig sslProtocol="TLS"
                     protocols="${server.tlsProtocols}"
                     ciphers="${server.cipher.suites.List}"
                     honorCipherOrder="true">
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="<omitted>"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="<omitted>"
                     certificateKeyPassword="<omitted>" />
      </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

However, when tomcat starts up, I get the following error in catalina.out:

```
21-Jul-2021 15:03:19.083 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8443]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:875)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:632)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:655)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:995)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the [protocols] specified are supported by the SSL engine : [[server.tlsProtocols]]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.getEnabled(SSLUtilBase.java:92)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLUtilBase.<init>(SSLUtilBase.java:56)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEUtil.<init>(JSSEUtil.java:144)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation.getSSLUtil(JSSEImplementation.java:50)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.createSSLContext(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:103)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.initialiseSsl(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:86)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:244)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1087)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:265)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:581)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:993)
        ... 13 more
```

I can use jcmd to see what system properties the process has set:

```
$ $JAVA_HOME/bin/jcmd 1694 VM.system_properties

...
server.cipher.suites.List=TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV

...
server.tlsProtocols=TLSv1.2
...
```

So it seems that the process has the correct system properties, but they are not being substituted in server.xml.

I tried setting the properties in the JVM options instead (ie: -Dserver.tlsProtocols=TLSv1.2), but the result is the same. The JVM has the property, but it isn't being substituted.

I can set the properties in the server.xml file and the system starts up, but after that it doesn't seem to be parsing the web.xml file properly either (JSP pages aren't working), so I'm trying to get this figured out first in case the root cause is the same.

Has anyone seen this before? This is in a docker image, in case that means anything. My user has ownership of all the files and directories, but I would think I'd have other issues if that was the problem. I have another system that isn't in a docker image and it parses the files correctly, so that's my next plan of attack.

It's tomcat 8.5.34, and I can't really change that.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the issue.

We have a custom PROPERTY_SOURCE configured that handles encrypted passwords. Normally this custom class returns the system property if the property value doesn't follow a specific pattern representing an encrypted password.

Debugging that class, I could see that it was expecting a configuration file to be present in a specific location, and failed silently when the file was not available. Putting the config file where it was expected fixed the problem.

This link pointed me in the right direction:

[Environment/system variables in server.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11926181/environment-system-variables-in-server-xml)

Answer (score 0):

From [tomcat-8.5-doc](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support_-_SSLHostConfig):

> sslProtocol
>
> JSSE only.
>
> The SSL protocol(s) to use (a single value may enable multiple
> protocols - see the JVM documentation for details). If not specified,
> the default is TLS. The permitted values may be obtained from the JVM
> documentation for the allowed values for algorithm when creating an
> SSLContext instance e.g. Oracle Java 7. Note: **There is overlap between
> this attribute and protocols.**

You could try just by using `protocols` attribute and remove `sslProtocol="TLS"`

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: I would try setting an explicit protocol instead of `protocol="HTTP/1.1"` as `protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"`. Would also try changing the property prefix to say `custom.tlsProtocols`  or not using the property at all to see if it works. It might be a bug.